# Java: Get rid of `Cipher.init()` overhead

Tags: java, performance, encryption, aes

I need to increase performance of the following method:

```
private byte[] decrypt(final byte[] encrypted, final Key key) throws ... {
    this.cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key);
    return this.cipher.doFinal(encrypted);
}
```

The `cipher` object ("AES/ECB/NoPadding") is initialized in the constructor, so that it can be reused. ECB is used since the `encrypted` array will contain always only 16 bytes of data (i.e. 1 block of data). 128 bit key is used.

This method is called millions of times to decrypt 16 byte chunk, each time with a different key. E.g. the method is called like this:

```
final List<Key> keys = List with millions of keys
final byte[] data = new byte[] { ... 16 bytes of data go here ...}

for (final Key key : keys) {
    final byte[] encrypted = decrypt(data, key);

    // Do something with encrypted
}
```

The `Cipher.init()` takes most of the time of the `decrypt` method, since the data is so small. I.e. with over 12 million invocations, `Cipher.init()` takes 3 microseconds on average while `Cipher.doFinal()` takes < 0.5 microseconds on average.

- What takes so long in `Cipher.init()`?
- Is there any way to speed up this code using Java only? For instance by taking advantage of the fact I will be decrypting always only a single block of data?
- Would it be faster to use a C/C++ implementation and call it using JNI? If so, is there any well-established library for that?

I use JDK 1.8.0_73 and my processor supports AES-NI.

Comment: Are the potential keys always the same?  In other words, will you run the same list of keys over each 16 byte chunk?  Or does each 16 byte chunk have their own list of keys?

Comment: Key setup takes a while. I don't think, you can make it faster with Java alone.

Comment: @Pace: The keys change, but not that often. Are you thinking of storing the initialized `Cipher` objects?

Comment: @Augustin Yes, that was my thought.

Comment: Just call `Cipher.init()` only once (in the constructor)

Comment: p.s. thanks for question about C/C++. Why I didn't think about

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> What takes so long in Cipher.init()?

During initialization a user-supplied key data is expanded into session keys used by encryption and decryption routines.

> Is there any way to speed up this code using Java only? For instance by taking advantage of the fact I will be decrypting always only a single block of data?

Yes, but this would require rewriting the essential part of AES algorithm. You may find it in JDK sources in [AESCrypt.java](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8u/jdk8u/jdk/file/0f6de62683a2/src/share/classes/com/sun/crypto/provider/AESCrypt.java).

Alternatively, you may store a list of preinitialized Ciphers instead of Keys.

> Would it be faster to use a C/C++ implementation and call it using JNI? If so, is there any well-established library for that?

Most likely, yes. `libcrypto` which is a part of OpenSSL will help. [Here is an example](https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/EVP_Symmetric_Encryption_and_Decryption).

Comment: In the end (and in my use-case), storing the pre-initialized `Cipher` objects led to about 10 times speed-up. Thanks.